# Capture information in a list using bs4 when a table is embedded in the list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, html-table

For this html code:

```
<ul><li>Include these codes as defined in http://unitsofmeasure.org
    <table><tr><td><b>Code</b>
    </td><td><b>Display</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>min</td><td>Minute</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>h</td><td>Hour</td><td></td></tr><tr>
    <td>d</td><td>Day</td><td></td></tr>
    </table></li></ul>
```

I just want the information in `<li>` section, I mean `"Include these codes as defined in http://unitsofmeasure.org"`. But because `</li>` is ended after table, `BS4` also captures information in the table. This is my code:

```
definition = [li.get_text() for li in ul.findAll("li")]
```

And this is the output:

```
[u'Include these codes as defined in http://unitsofmeasure.orgCodeDisplayminMinutehHourdDaywkWeekmoMonthaYear']
```

How can I edit the code to not capture information in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [extract()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) to remove the table.

```
definition = [li.find('table').extract().get_text() for li in ul.findAll("li")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move up from **table** tag using ***previousSibling***, more info about available methods at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names

```
t = soup.find('table')
print t.previousSibling
```